# Filtering one IQueryable List with another

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, nopcommerce

I have two lists as below:

```
var processedOrders = this._requestReviewRecordService.GetAll().ToList();
var orders = _orderRepository.Table.Where(o => o.OrderStatusId == (int)OrderStatus.Complete && o.CreatedOnUtc < EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(DateTime.Now, -minutes)).ToList();
```

The lists are of different types, but both contain a property called OrderId.

Essentially I want to filter the second list "orders" of any records that a matching OrderId.

I've tried Linq's Except method, but this seems to only play nicely with primitive types.

Can anyone point me in the right direction - I didnt think this would be quite so challenging!

Thanks in advance
Al

Comment: Are you using linq to entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample that does what you're after:

```
public class TypeOne
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string SomeOtherField { get; set; }
    }

    public class TypeTwo
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string MainField { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // A little bit of setup
            var first = new List<TypeOne>() { new TypeOne { OrderId = 1, SomeOtherField = "One" }, new TypeOne { OrderId = 2,  SomeOtherField = "Two" } } ;
            var second = new List<TypeTwo>() { new TypeTwo { OrderId = 1, MainField = "One" }, new TypeTwo { OrderId = 2, MainField = "Two" }, new TypeTwo { OrderId = 3, MainField = "Buckle" }, new TypeTwo { OrderId = 4, MainField = "MyShoe" } };

            // Here's where we do the interesting bit
            var firstIds = from id in first
                           select id.OrderId;

            var query = from item in second
                        where firstIds.Contains(item.OrderId)
                        select item;


            // And some boring results
            foreach (var i in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[OrderId: {0}, MainField: {1}]", i.OrderId, i.MainField));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Keep in mind that this example uses simple lists as the stores for the objects. This approach doesn't always work if you're using an Entitiy Framework EntitySet as the source collection in any of your queries, because they haven't implemented an extension method for Contains<>() that works with EF. That being said, you could materialise your queries in to lists first, and then this approach would work.